# Use of JavaFX Binding in UI synchronization

Tags: java, javafx, binding

I struggle with the basic design decision for developing editor dialogs for objects in JavaFX. Oracle states in their article Using JavaFX Properties and Binding "..binding could be used in a graphical user interface (GUI) that automatically keeps its display synchronized with the application's underlying data." This idea makes a lot of sense in the first place but I am struggling how to apply this if the user interface follows the maybe old way of having a "OK" and a "Cancel" button.
In the "OK" szenario everything is easy: If a user wants to edit an object, first I would create the editor ui. Next, I would pass the according object that I want to edit to the editor. When I set the object I would bind the attributes of the object to the according ui controls e.g. StringProperties of the obect to TextProperties of TextFields. Now I can edit the object and once I click OK, I unbind all the bindings everything is fine. That is the scenario for which I find on many code snippets in the web.

But what about the "Cancel" scenario? This makes it rather complicated, because I think I first have to create some sort of clone of the object that I want to edit, in order to return the unchanged object if the operation was cancelled. However, this necessity to clone upfront is nowhere mentioned.

Alternative to binding,  maybe old way, of setting the objects attribut values into the controls e.g. using setText of TextFields, edit, and once "OK" is selected, to update the object using getText from the TextField the more straight forward way?! And yes, I get that this prevents the update of the ui, if my object is changed during the edit operation from some other activity.

I wonder is binding the way to go as Oracle states and if so, how to do it that it supports the OK and Cancel scenario?

Comment: You have pretty much answered your own question: if you want "live editing" (so the main view updates as the user types in the edit dialog), you can use binding but need to manage reversion on cancel by hand. If you don't want "live editing", don't use binding but update the properties on user commit. Note you can still bind to the model properties in the main view in either case.

Comment: The DirtyFX library is the answer that you're looking for:  https://github.com/thomasnield/DirtyFX  It's an implementation of the most (all?) of the Observable interfaces that supports the idea of "basing".  It's mostly intended to be able to tell if a value has changed, but I you can revert the values using reset().  Use these implementations instead of Simple{Type}Property.

Comment: There is the (unfortunately) largely unmaintained [UndoFX library](https://github.com/FXMisc/UndoFX), which is "a general-purpose undo manager for JavaFX (or Java applications in general)."  I am not sure if that is anything like what you are looking for, but on a cursory glance it appears to have some of the facilities you want.  It is not exactly as you describe, but perhaps it could be adapted to be part of a solution you craft using the library to help manage undo operations (e.g. the "Cancel scenario").